# Can one uniquely initialize each object created by the create_list method in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

In order to do this, I imagine passing an array of hashes to the `create_list` method.  I am considering something that would look like this:

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(
  :person, 3, [
    {name: 'Rebekah', description: 'A woman with straight brown hair'}, 
    {name: 'Day', description: 'A man with curly brown hair'}, 
    {name: 'Ihsan', description: 'A boy with wavy blond hair'}
  ]
)
```

This would persist three objects initialized with the custom name and description values.

Is there any way to do this directly or ought I just loop through the array creating an individual instance with each set of unique values?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need them to be different? If you do, I see two options:

1- Set up the factory properties in a sequence. Like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Person number #{n}" }
  end
```

2- Create a list and set them up individually

```
list = FactoryGirl.create_list(:person, 3)
    list.each do |person|
    #setting up
end
```

There are other answers, but I would go with the first